# media codec sample implementation in android 4.1

Tags: android, gstreamer, android-4.2-jelly-bean, java-gstreamer

I am trying to display video buffers on an android. I am using the media codec API released in Android 4.1 Jelly Bean.

The sample goes like this:

```
 MediaCodec codec = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(type);
 codec.configure(format, ...);
```

configure method accepts 3 other arguments, apart from MediaFormat. I have been able to figure out MediaFormat somehow but I am not sure about the other 3 parameters. (below).

```
 MediaSurface, MediaCrypto and Flags.
```

Any leads?

Also, what should I do with the MediaCrypto argument, if I am not encrypting my video buffers.

Requirements:

```
1) Decode the buffers on the android device, 
2) Display them on the screen.
```

Comment: Have a look at the example provided in the answer to my question [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418093/mime-type-of-android-camera-previewformat

Answer (score 1):

You can see the article from here:
http://dpsm.wordpress.com/2012/07/28/android-mediacodec-decoded/

Comment: It is usually helpful to include important/useful points from the linked posting in your answer so that your answer actually has some value on its own, particularly if that link stops working.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness:

To decode -

**MediaSurface** is the surface to render the frame to ( or null if not rendering )

**MediaCrypto** should be null if the is no encryption

**flags** == 0 if decoding or MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE if encoding

Comment: how to get crypto scheme UUID?