# Connect MediaCodec with Camera (setPreviewCallbackWithBuffers)

Tags: android, android-camera, media, codec

As @Aegonis asked in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458289/encoding-h-264-from-camera-with-android-mediacodec)

I'm trying to connect the Camera with Android to encode the video frames.

The problem is, trying to do the same than him, in this part, as another 2 users that posted in his topic, it crash:

```
// called from Camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(...) in other class
public void encoder(byte[] input) {
try {
    ByteBuffer[] inputBuffers = mediaCodec.getInputBuffers();
    ByteBuffer[] outputBuffers = mediaCodec.getOutputBuffers();
    int inputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(-1);
    if (inputBufferIndex >= 0) {
        ByteBuffer inputBuffer = inputBuffers[inputBufferIndex];
        inputBuffer.clear();
        inputBuffer.put(input);
        mediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, input.length, 0, 0);
    }
...
```

The call i do from setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer is like this:

```
    int bufSize= 460800;
        camera.addCallbackBuffer(new byte[bufSize]);
        camera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new PreviewCallback() {

            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
                    codecs.encoder(data);
            }
        });
...
```

Having the following error messages

```
03-04 20:30:46.762: E/AndroidRuntime(26196): java.nio.BufferOverflowException
03-04 20:30:46.762: E/AndroidRuntime(26196): at java.nio.Buffer.checkPutBounds(Buffer.java:189)
03-04 20:30:46.762: E/AndroidRuntime(26196): at java.nio.ReadWriteDirectByteBuffer.put(ReadWriteDirectByteBuffer.java:100)
03-04 20:30:46.762: E/AndroidRuntime(26196): at java.nio.ByteBuffer.put(ByteBuffer.java:712)
```

So well, the byte buffer is so big, but setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer says you to use at least one buffer with the size: 460800. So... how would you solve this problem?

Comment: I added some information to @Aegonis' post that describes the new features in Android 4.3 (API 18).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Parameters camParams = camera.getParameters();
int size = imageWidth * imageHeight;
size  = size * ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(camParams.getPreviewFormat()) / 8;
mBuffer = new byte[size]; // class variable
camera.addCallbackBuffer(mBuffer);
```