# Mediacodec and camera, color space incorrect

Tags: android, colors, h.264

By referring Aegonis's [work 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458289/encoding-h-264-from-camera-with-android-mediacodec) and [work 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703596/mediacodec-and-camera-colorspaces-dont-match), I also got the H.264 stream , but the color is not correct. I am using HTC Butterfly for development. Here is part of my code:

Camera:

```
parameters.setPreviewSize(width, height);
parameters.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.YV12);
parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(frameRate);
```

MediaCodec:

```
mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");
MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 320, 240);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 500000);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 15);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);   
mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE); 
mediaCodec.start();
```

When using **COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar** the error shows "[OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc] does not support color format 19,"  so I can only use "**COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar**". Does anyone know the reason why no support?

Got it, by using :

```
int colorFormat = 0;
    MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities capabilities = codecInfo.getCapabilitiesForType(mimeType);
    for (int i = 0; i < capabilities.colorFormats.length && colorFormat == 0; i++) {
        int format = capabilities.colorFormats[i];
        Log.e(TAG, "Using color format " + format);           
    }
```

we can have color format **21** (COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar) and **2130708361** (no corresponding format), I think the format will change depends on device.

Then, I tried the color transform provided from the suggestions in [work 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458289/encoding-h-264-from-camera-with-android-mediacodec) and [work 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703596/mediacodec-and-camera-colorspaces-dont-match):

```
public static byte[] YV12toYUV420PackedSemiPlanar(final byte[] input, final byte[] output, final int width, final int height) {
    /* 
     * COLOR_TI_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar is NV12
     * We convert by putting the corresponding U and V bytes together (interleaved).
     */
    final int frameSize = width * height;
    final int qFrameSize = frameSize/4;

    System.arraycopy(input, 0, output, 0, frameSize); // Y

    for (int i = 0; i < qFrameSize; i++) {
        output[frameSize + i*2] = input[frameSize + i + qFrameSize]; // Cb (U)
        output[frameSize + i*2 + 1] = input[frameSize + i]; // Cr (V)
    }
    return output;
}

public static byte[] YV12toYUV420Planar(byte[] input, byte[] output, int width, int height) {
    /* 
     * COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar is I420 which is like YV12, but with U and V reversed.
     * So we just have to reverse U and V.
     */
    final int frameSize = width * height;
    final int qFrameSize = frameSize/4;

    System.arraycopy(input, 0, output, 0, frameSize); // Y
    System.arraycopy(input, frameSize, output, frameSize + qFrameSize, qFrameSize); // Cr (V)
    System.arraycopy(input, frameSize + qFrameSize, output, frameSize, qFrameSize); // Cb (U)

    return output;
}

public static byte[] swapYV12toI420(byte[] yv12bytes, int width, int height) {
    byte[] i420bytes = new byte[yv12bytes.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < width*height; i++)
        i420bytes[i] = yv12bytes[i];
    for (int i = width*height; i < width*height + (width/2*height/2); i++)
        i420bytes[i] = yv12bytes[i + (width/2*height/2)];
    for (int i = width*height + (width/2*height/2); i < width*height + 2*(width/2*height/2); i++)
        i420bytes[i] = yv12bytes[i - (width/2*height/2)];
    return i420bytes;
}
```

Obviously, the color transform of **YV12toYUV420PackedSemiPlanar** performs better than the other two. It is relatively better but still looks different in comparison with the real color. Is there something wrong with my code? Any comment will be appreciated.

Comment: +1 for writing the question in such a way.

Comment: "different" like the chroma channels are backward, or "different" like things are subtly off?  (If you rearrange `YV12toYUV420PackedSemiPlanar` to swap the Cb/Cr channels, does it look right?)

Comment: I tried to swap Cb/Cr and the color is incorrect. I also try just show the color of Y and it seems the video is been put on a green mask, that is not as what I expect. I really can not figure out what is happening.

Comment: If it's relatively subtle it could be a gamut problem.  BT.601 says the Y channel should go from 16 to 235, but maybe the camera is outputting 0-255?  If that's the issue you could try scaling it (set it to Y*(219/255)+16 as you copy it).

Comment: Hi Fadden, thanks for your suggestion. I tested, but the color again seems incorrect. And I observed that the pixel value are vary from -128 to 127 for Y, Cb and Cr. I thought the pixel value should between 0 to 255.

Comment: The color format is set as "COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar", I guess because of this setting results the pixel value vary from -128 to 127 for Y, Cb and Cr.

Comment: color format 2130708361 corresponds to COLOR_FormatSurface, perhaps your question was asked before API 18 was released.

Comment: 2130708361 -> COLOR_FormatSurface -> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.html#COLOR_FormatSurface

Answer (score 3):

Got it, now the color looks good, the test is based on HTC Butterfly. 
When set the resolution to 320x240, your color transform should looks like:

```
    System.arraycopy(input, 0, output, 0, frameSize);
    for (int i = 0; i < (qFrameSize); i++) {  
        output[frameSize + i*2] = (input[frameSize + qFrameSize + i - 32 - 320]);  
        output[frameSize + i*2 + 1] = (input[frameSize + i - 32 - 320]);            
    }
```

for resolution 640x480 and above,

```
System.arraycopy(input, 0, output, 0, frameSize);    
    for (int i = 0; i < (qFrameSize); i++) {  
        output[frameSize + i*2] = (input[frameSize + qFrameSize + i]);  
        output[frameSize + i*2 + 1] = (input[frameSize + i]);   
    }
```

For the frame rate issue, we can use the getSupportedPreviewFpsRange() to check the supported frame rate range of our device as:

```
List<int[]> fpsRange = parameters.getSupportedPreviewFpsRange();
for (int[] temp3 : fpsRange) {
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp3));}
```

And the following setting works correct when play the encoded H.264 ES,

```
parameters.setPreviewFpsRange(29000, 30000);    
//parameters.setPreviewFpsRange(4000,60000);//this one results fast playback when I use the FRONT CAMERA
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Albert. Great research. I am wondering  why there's -352 bytes padding when writing U and V components for 320x240 resolution? And which padding should I use for 960x720 resolution?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493169/getting-qualcomm-encoders-to-work-via-mediacodec-api/19883163 It seems that when sending frame to encoder, Y component should be aligned by some number of bytes for certain resolutions.

Answer (score 2):

After reading [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-platform/awaNwgb6EbY/a-YiIOwaL0QJ) it turns out that more generalised way for encoding frames
of various resolutions is to align chroma plane by 2048 bytes before sending frame to the `MediaCodec`. This is actual for `QualComm` (`OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc`) encoder which I believe HTC Butterfly has, but still does not works well for all resolutions. `720x480` and `176x144` are still have chroma  plane misaligned according to the output video. Also, avoid resolutions which sizes can't be divided by 16.

The transformation is pretty simple:

```
int padding = 0;
if (mediaCodecInfo.getName().contains("OMX.qcom")) {
  padding = (width * height) % 2048;
}
byte[] inputFrameBuffer = new byte[frame.length];
byte[] inputFrameBufferWithPadding = new byte[padding + frame.length];

ColorHelper.NV21toNV12(frame, inputFrameBuffer, width, height);
# copy Y plane
System.arraycopy(inputFrameBuffer, 0, inputFrameBufferWithPadding, 0, inputFrameBuffer.length);
int offset = width * height;
# copy U and V planes aligned by <padding> boundary
System.arraycopy(inputFrameBuffer, offset, inputFrameBufferWithPadding, offset + padding, inputFrameBuffer.length - offset);
```