# How to get stride and Y plane alignment values for MediaCodec encoder

Tags: android, encoding, android-mediacodec

There's a few related questions and discussions on this subject:

- [Mediacodec and camera, color space incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739684/mediacodec-and-camera-color-space-incorrect)
- [Getting QualComm encoders to work via MediaCodec API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493169/getting-qualcomm-encoders-to-work-via-mediacodec-api)
- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-platform/awaNwgb6EbY/a-YiIOwaL0QJ
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37769

I am feeding camera preview frames (`NV21` converted to `NV12`) to `MediaCodec` encoder (`NV12` aka `COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar`). It looks like that on some devices with `QualComm` encoder which are running Android versions less than `4.3` I have to do some input frames processing in order to receive back frame with correct color.

On `Sony Xperia ZR` running `Android 4.2.2` I have to add `Y` plane alignment in order to make it working on almost all resolutions. Code above adds `1024` bytes alignment for widths which can not be divided by `32` and `2048` bytes alignment for other resolutions. It makes `MediaCodec` to encode frames properly for all resolutions which can be divided by `16` (except `176x144` for which `UV` plane looks misaligned).

```
int getYPadding() {
    if (mediaCodecInfo.getName().contains("OMX.qcom") && android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 18) {
        if ((getWidth() % 32) != 0) {
            return (getWidth()*getHeight()) % 1024;
        } else {
            return (getWidth()*getHeight()) % 2048;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to test this alignment on `LG G2` which is running same `Android 4.2.2` and has `QualComm` encoder, and it looks like it does not working on it correctly. `UV` plane is misaligned (a green stripe at the bottom of the frame). I was not able to calculate the padding which will work for both phones.

I also have access to `Sony Xperia Z1` running `Android 4.3` with `QualComm` chipset and it looks like it does not have such problems. Video on every resolution looks fine and `Y` plane does not needs to be aligned anyhow.

I understand that it's hardware-related and might be complicated, but since I have to support users running Android prior to `4.3` I have a question. Is it possible to programmatically determine `Y` plane alignment and vertical / horizontal stride values which encoder is expecting for the given color format?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem in a nutshell: there were no [CTS tests](http://source.android.com/compatibility/cts-intro.html) for video encoding until Android 4.3 (API 18).

As a result, the behavior of `MediaCodec` across different devices was inconsistent, and a few bugs went unnoticed.  The [EncodeDecodeTest](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#EncodeDecodeTest) tests exercise the functions you're asking about, and as a result you can reliably feed YUV data to a 4.3+ device (though you still have to runtime-detect whether it wants planar or semi-planar).

For your specific question, the Y plane on older Qualcomm devices needs to be aligned at a 2K boundary, which isn't quite what your code is doing.  For 720p video this happens naturally (720*1280 == 450 * 2048), for 176x144 you'd adjust by 1280 to start the UV plane at 26624 instead of 25344.  You need to set the absolute alignment within the buffer, not a fixed amount of padding -- use `uvoffset = (width*height + 2047) & ~2047`.

You will need to detect the codec vendor and Android software version, and if it's Qualcomm on pre-4.3 you need to make this adjustment.  If your requirements change, and you can target API 18+, these issues go away.  (And you can use `Surface` input to `MediaCodec`, which avoids the U/V swap issue, though depending on your needs that may not be useful.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @fadden You're awesome! :) With correct way of aligning I finally able to make it working for all resolutions on `Sony Xperia ZR`. It's still buggy on `LG G2`, but I think I'll wrap it up into a separate question and attach some screenshots.

Comment: Adding on to this, more likely you would like to align Y plane and UV plane too at a 2K boundary. E.g. for a RGB-video resolution of say 480x480, the yuv420Buffer that is to be passed to MediaCodec should be of size: YUVBufferSize + yOffset + uvOffset which translates to: (480 * 480 * 1.5) + (2048 - ((480 * 480) % 2048)) + (2048 - ((480 * 480 / 2) % 2048)). I don't know which Encoder does LG_G2 use, if it's qcom-encoder, then you may try this logic. Hope this helps.