# Finding valid capture size for Android adb screenrecord

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, screen-recording

I am using the Android 4.4 `screenrecord` command to record the screen of some different devices, but if I use the `--size` parameter then the capture video is corrupted.

How can I get the list of valid `screenrecord` sizes for a given device's encoder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such list.  At least, not one that includes *all* valid resolutions.

Any size that is listed in the [AVC profile list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC) will work if the encoder supports that profile level, and you *can* get that by querying `MediaCodec`.  From code written in the Java programming language, you just need to get a `MediaCodecInfo` for AVC, then use `getCapabilitiesForType()` to get a `CodecCapabilities` object, from which you can get an array of [CodecProfileLevel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecProfileLevel.html).  The `CodecProfileLevel` class includes the AVC profile level constants.  (I'm not sure offhand what the private native equivalents of this is.)

Many resolutions that are not explicitly supported will happen to work.  The probability of an arbitrary MxN resolution working is much higher if both M and N are multiples of 16 (with an additional allowance for 1080).  However, some devices are more limited (see e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579865/nexus-7-2013-mediacodec-video-encoder-garbled-output)).

Comment: I managed to get the supported profile/levels , but how can I calculate from that, what are the supported sizes ?

Comment: Make a table from the AVC standard (or at least the AVC wikipedia page linked earlier).  You can see an example of it being used to determine width/height/fps for test cases in one of the CTS tests: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/kitkat-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/EncodeVirtualDisplayWithCompositionTest.java (find `getAvcSupportedFormatInfo()`).  Some of the other tests should have a similar check, e.g. low-end devices might not support 720p encoding but a couple of the existing tests require it.