# Android MediaCodec video wrong color and playing too fast

Tags: android, android-camera, yuv, android-mediacodec

I am encoding a video using MediaCodec using Camera's setPreviewCallback.
(I follow this example [Encoding H.264 from camera with Android MediaCodec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458289/encoding-h-264-from-camera-with-android-mediacodec)).
I use the follow setting for the MediaCodec:

```
mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType("video/avc");
MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", 1280, 720);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 8000000);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, 30);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar);
mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 5);
mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
mediaCodec.start();
```

My Camera setting are:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
parameters.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);
parameters.setPictureSize(previewWidth, 1280);
parameters.setPreviewSize(previewWidth, 720);
parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(30);
parameters.setPreviewFpsRange(5000,30000);
mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
```

I got a video but there are two problems:

1. its colors are wrong.
2. its playing too fast.

Here is an example video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1Eg2bvrHLM&feature=youtu.be

Does any of you guys know what are the causes of this two problem? And may be tell me some ways to solve this problem because I am totally lost/confused now.
thanks for reading and would appreciate any comments and opinions.

Comment: And here is a link that will show the ordering of the bytes for YUV420SemiPlanar vs YUV420Planar (http://www.symlab.org/main/documentation/reference/s3/pdk/GUID-D429672C-448D-5E91-ABA0-81680869D69E.html). I hope it can help others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The YUV formats used by `Camera` output and `MediaCodec` input have their U/V planes swapped.

If you are able to move the data through a `Surface` you can avoid this issue; however, you lose the ability to examine the YUV data.  An example of recording to a .mp4 file from a camera can be found on [bigflake](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/#CameraToMpegTest).

Some details about the colorspaces and how to swap them is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703596/mediacodec-and-camera-colorspaces-dont-match).

There is no timestamp information in the raw H.264 elementary stream.  You need to pass the timestamp through the decoder to `MediaMuxer` or whatever you're using to create your final output.  If you don't, the player will just pick a rate, or possibly play the frames as fast as it can.

Comment: Hi fadden, I finally solved the coloring problem. You led me to the right direction and is right that there are some color swapping work to be done. I have to swap the ordering the U and V byte in the incoming byte[] array (the one from onPreviewFrame). The only differences between my situation and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703596/mediacodec-and-camera-colorspaces-dont-match is that I have a COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar instead of COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar. After looking up and comparing semi-planar vs planar, I finally understand how to swap them. thanks again.